# Por qué SocketIo escucha dos veces seguidas el mismo emit

Tags: nodejs, socket.io

Que tal, buenas tardes, me ha surgido un problema usando NodeJs y SocketIo en el servidor conectandome desde una App Android con el siguiente esquema:

1 - La App hace un `emit` de la forma:

```
socket.emit("insertarObjeto", {"objeto": {
    "codigoObjeto": 1
    , "nombreObjeto": "objeto 1"
    , "detallesObjeto": { 
           "color": "blanco"
           , "medidas": "125"
           , "unidadDeMedida": "centimetros"
         }
   }
});
```

2 -  En el servidor se escucha de la forma:

```
socket.on("insertarObjeto",function(data){
   console.dir(data);
})
```

3 - Resulta que el servidor hace dos veces seguidas el `console.dir(data);` del paso anterior, con una mínima diferencia de 1 segundo. Ya revise si en algún otro lado estaba escuchando nuevamente ese `emit` pero nada que ver.

---

¿Alguien tiene idea de que podría ser?

- En el servidor estoy utilizando **SocketIo 1.4.8** y **NodeJs 6.11.0**
- En la App estoy utilizando **SocketIo 1.4.4**

Comment: asegúrate que solo haces un único emit en el app

Comment: ¿Tienes algún modo de verificar que tu app de Android haga una vez la petición? el código hace lo que le dices que haga, si hace la petición dos veces es porque le llega el evento, luego el evento se ejecuta dos veces. Quizá el asunto está en cómo la app de Android dispara el evento

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, les comento, he estado haciendo debug a la app y pues he colocado unos alerts y console.log para verificar cuantas veces pasa por el fragmento que hace el emit y efectivamente solo pasa una vez y justo cuando pasa el servidor lo escucha pero al segundo el servidor vuelve a escuchar el evento y la app no ha emitido nada.

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal ? has podido solucionar el problema porque tengo uno similar pero a la inversa mi servidor envia solo 1 emit y lo eh comprobado con console.log y efectivamente se envia solo una vez pero no se porque mi cliente los escucha 2 veces o mas

dejo lo de arriba para ponerlos en contexto de como solucionarlo
En mi caso estaba usando react native y debes poner todos los socket.on
dentro de UseEffect y luego poner un return con un socket.off('channel')

```
useEffect(()=>{

    socket.on('ticketEdited', async (tickets)=>{
        setTickets(tickets)
        console.log('1')
        
    })

    socket.on('ticketNotification', (datos)=>{
        const {mesa_ticket , cuenta_ticket} = datos
        const NOTIFICATION_TITLE = cuenta_ticket[0].empleado
        const NOTIFICATION_BODY = 'Modifico la mesa' + ' ' + mesa_ticket[0].numero
        const CLICK_MESSAGE = 'Notification clicked!'

        console.log(cuenta_ticket[0].empleado)

        new Notification(NOTIFICATION_TITLE, { body: NOTIFICATION_BODY })
        .onclick = () => console.log(CLICK_MESSAGE)
    })

    return () =>{
        socket.off('ticketEdited')
        socket.off('ticketNotification')

    }
},[])
```

esto de arriba es un ejemplo de mi codigo ahora creo que tu problema puede ser algo similar si estas utilizando react lo cual no se pero si lo haces quizas te sirva poner el emit en el UseEffect y luego ponerlo en el return